# how to remove node from firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I'm trying to delete node from firebase in android.

**Problem:**
 Node is deleting successfully but at the same time a new node is creating in firebase. I don't know what's the problem.

**reference of database**

```
activeCase = database.getReference("Active Case").child(subEmail);
```

**here is code to remove**

```
activeCase.removeValue(new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@Nullable DatabaseError databaseError, @NonNull DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "onComplete:1 "+databaseError); // no error here
                                Log.d(TAG, "onComplete:2 "+databaseReference); // address of node is showing here
                                availableStatus = "available";
                               // onMapPress(view); // function
                            }
                        });
```

[here is image of node that I wants to delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Zt0I.png)

[image: i wants to delete node of id jazz9999@gmail it is deleting but a new node with same id and child created automatically.]

Comment: What do you mean through "but at the same time a new node with same id, child and info is automatically creating"? Where is this created?

Comment: @AlexMamo new node is creating in firebase. i wants to delete node of id jazz9999@gmail it is deleting but a new node with same id and child created automatically.

Comment: Please share more code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply use this.

```
dbreference.child(id).removeValue();
```